# SQL Modulus operator confusion

Tags: sql, operator-keyword

Suppose I write a query to find the emails of all members who do not have email addresses that end in ".com".

(All valid emails should be considered)

### Members

MemberId, FirstName, LastName, Email

SELECT Email FROM Members WHERE Email NOT LIKE "%.com";

Why is this query incorrect?

Comment: That is a wildcard not modulus

Comment: If it's throwing an error, it might be due to the use of double quotes instead of single quotes.  Hard to tell without knowing which database engine you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `or email is null` part. And a `lower(email)` could be a bit more error proof.

(Otherwise I don't think this is called modulus operator.)